# Intune deployed appx Packages dont show up in Company Portal

Tags: deployment, microsoft-intune

i tried to deploy an appx Package für my enrolled Windows Phone 8.1 Devices in Intune. The App is visible in in Intune but dont Show up in the Company Portal. Using the same Procedure (described below) for classic XAP Packages works like a charm. Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Here ist what i had done:

1. Build Standard Universal App in Visual Studio 2013 (Hub App)
2. Used the Store -> Create App Packages from within Visual Studio
3. Used the BuildMDILAPPX.ps1 Script to pack and sign the App with out Symantec Code Signing Certificate
4. Uploaded the App to Intune and choosed to Deploy for "all users" as a available install.

From here the App Shows up in Management Portal as available - Did i missed anything? 
Are there any Special Tasks i have to do, to make my appx Package available for my Windows Phone users? Btq: The **same Procedure** for XAP Packages works just fine.

Any Suggestions, Tipps or Hints?

Thanks in Advance,

Matthias

Comment: *Plonk* - appx packages were not supported by Intune in my Region by that Date. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. Latest Intune Updates were not rolled out in my Region by that date. Works like a charm now.